# Confirm password mat-error - Angular / Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-forms

I have this basic password confirmation form using Angular & Material. The inputs are supposed to display errors when :

- The password is empty (it works)
- The password doesn't match the pattern (it works)
- The confirm_password is empty (it works)
- The confirm_password doesn't match the password **(it  doesn't works)**

The problem is that the confirm_password input does not detect the error, so it doesn't display the according **mat-error**. Is there any way to make the confirm_password input display the error when it's not equal to the first one without using custom validators?

Here's the code, I simplified it as much as I could. Thank you!

```
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        
        <input
          matInput
          name="password"
          type="password"
          [(ngModel)]="password"
          required
          pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,20}$"/>

        <mat-error
          *ngIf=" myForm.controls['password'] && (myForm.controls['password'].dirty || myForm.submitted) && myForm.controls['password'].hasError('required')">

          Password is required

        </mat-error>

        <mat-error
          *ngIf="myForm.controls['password'] && (myForm.controls['password'].dirty || myForm.submitted) && myForm.controls['password'].hasError('pattern')">

          Password should have at least 6 characters : one lowercase, one uppercase and one digit.

        </mat-error>

      </mat-form-field>



      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Confirm password</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          name="confirm_password"
          type="password"
          [(ngModel)]="confirmPassword"
          ngModel
          required
        />

        <mat-error
          *ngIf="myForm.controls['confirm_password'] && (myForm.controls['confirm_password'].dirty || myForm.submitted) && myForm.controls['confirm_password'].hasError('required')">

          Please confirm your password

        </mat-error>

        <mat-error
          *ngIf="myForm.controls['confirm_password'] && (myForm.controls['confirm_password'].dirty || myForm.submitted) && myForm.controls['confirm_password'].value !== myForm.controls['password'].value">

          Password doesn't match

        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by naming your [(ngmodel)] same as the name attribute in the confirm password input? Also, in your myForm object, confirm password is confirmPassword or confirm_password. Can you paste your TS here?